# Accessing Windows 10 shares from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, windows, samba

Is there an easy method to connect to Windows 10 shares? I'm not using a Local Account, but a Microsoft Account (Online).

Answer (score 3):

### mount.cifs

This is more of a Linux question (I love those!)

You can mount Windows CIFS shares in a folder on your Pi [using the mount command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-cifs-windows-share/).
You can mount the shares at boot time by modifying `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 2):

Having wrestled with this and windows 10 I feel the OP's pain. Most problems stem from the fact that windows 10 forces SMB3 by default. Working with that configuration the following will work:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlmv2,username=YOUR_UN,password=YOUR_PW //192.168.0.255/path/to/remote/folder /path/to/pi/folder`

(obviously replace the ip address with the ip of the windows 10 machine hosting the share you wish to connect to)

IMPORTANT: This will fail unless you add a user account with that name and grant them access to the share by right clicking the folder in windows and selecting 'Give Access To...'. This is what I failed to do and have not seen this solution pointed out on the hundereds of posts that attempt to solve this problem. Where applicable, you may also need to give write permissions to that user in the folder properties/security section in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I found out when using the `mount -t cifs` command with Windows 10, if you don't use the `vers` option it will not connect.

so I'm betting with this option it will connect (hopefully):

```
root@osmc:/mnt/Video# mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlmv2,username=YourUsername,password=YourPassword,vers=2.1 //192.168.11.40/video /mnt/Video
```

If still not, try changing the `vers` from `2.1` to `1.0`

But still, after retrying a few times, it's not stable enough for me, it still sometimes won't connect.